# how to get squirrelmail, Apache2 and citadel working together?

Tags: mail-server, imap, email-client

I need to know how to get Apache2, citadel and squirrelmail to work together as citadel is a powerful and useful mail software.

The problem is that it can only receive mails from inside it's own environment, that being the mail server, but can't receive mail from anything else like g-mail for example.

Now i heard that squirrelmail might be the solution to this problem but i can't seem to find any explanation how to get it working.

and Apache2 oh boy that one is jsut being plain stuborn

update: well found a work around (not favorable) for apache2 for now all i need now is to get squirrelmail to work with citadel as citadel can send e-mails out to for example a hotmail account but it citadel can't receive it from those accounts which is a must

Comment: I used this Tutorial once for S-Mail. Not sure if it works for Citadel. https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p6

Comment: @EODCraftStaff it gets close and helps a lot but sadly it is not the solution